# MVC ActionFilter like attributes for WCF

Tags: wcf, custom-attributes, action-filter

Is there a way I can create custom method attributes for WCF that allow me to easily decorate a service method with a pre filter much like MVC uses action filters. I plan to use them for authentication and authorization. This is for a RESTful service whose requests are carrying an authentication cookie.

I am more interested in how to create the attributes rather than the authentication side of things. Does the HTTP Toolkit offer anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF has great extensibility - in many ways. You can encapsulate lots of functionality into e.g. service and/or operation behaviors, which can be attached to a service or operation by means of an attribute.

Check out the current [DotNet Rocks TV Show #202 with Miguel Castro](http://www.dnrtv.com/) on WCF extensibility - it should give you an idea of what is possible (and lots more is possible, for sure!)

See also:

- [WCF Extensibility Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751420%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [WCF Extensibility Deep Dive](http://weblogs.asp.net/gsusx/archive/2008/07/09/wcf-extensibility-deep-dive.aspx)
- [WCF Extensibility Screencast](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/aaron/archive/2006/06/07/26918.aspx)

Comment: URG this is a frustrating answer. Don't just give links to a bunch of verbose docs and screencasts, give an example.