# WCF ServiceFilter like ASP.NET MVC ActionFilter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

let's assume that the below one is our service contract;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace WCFSimple.Contract
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Ping(string name);
    }
}
```

the thing (I do not know what it is called but would appreciate if somebody could tell me) just above the `public interface IService` which is `[ServiceContract]` is giving me an idea.

I would like to have a simple thing called ActionFilter on ASP.NET MVC.

Can I do that on WCF? If I can, what can it give me to control there?

Comment: Duplicate of [MVC ActionFilter like attributes for WCF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812054/mvc-actionfilter-like-attributes-for-wcf) - see my answer to this question here and check out the resources I linked to

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) to do aspect-oriented programming in any .NET program, like ActionFilter in asp.net mvc (OnExecuting/OnBeforeExecuteing/OnExecuted/etc)

Comment: ok, on their home page there is a button called take a tour which I really do not need right now for a new library. There should be a way to get into there just like ActionFilters.